# Toplevel equivalent in PHP of "return" keyword outside function block?

Tags: php

Toplevel equivalent in PHP of "return" keyword outside function blocks ?

A nice, useful property of the `return` keyword is that when it is invoked,
it exits the main function block in which it is, no matter how many other 
nested blocks may surround it.

I am not aware of any equivalent for the toplevel scope. And I would like
to have a systematic way of "expanding" a function
call into an equivalent list of statements, and for that I need to know
a systematic way to deal with all the `return` ’s in the code.

Consider for example

```
function seekAUnicorn() 
{
   for($i=1;some_test($i);$i++) {
       for($j=1;some_test($j);$j++) {
          for($k=1;some_test($k);$k++) {
             if(unicorn_test_for_three_parameters($i,$j,$k)) return(array($i,$j,$k));
          }
          if(unicorn_test_for_two_parameters($i,$j)) return(array($i,$j));
       }
       if(unicorn_test_for_one_parameter($i)) return(array($i));
   }
}
```

The expansion of `$searchResult=seekAUnicorn();` might look something like this :

```
for($i=1;some_test($i);$i++) {
       for($j=1;some_test($j);$j++) {
          for($k=1;some_test($k);$k++) {
             if(unicorn_test_for_three_parameters($i,$j,$k))  {
              $searchResult = array($i,$j,$k);
              break 3;
             }
          }
          if(unicorn_test_for_two_parameters($i,$j)) {
            $searchResult = array($i,$j);
            break 2;
           } 
       }
       if(unicorn_test_for_one_parameter($i)){
            $searchResult = array($i);
            break;
        } 
   }
```

But to do it this way, you need to count the number of nested blocks 
around each nested return, which becomes painstaking and error-prone for
longer and more complicated code. Is there a simpler way ?

Comment: There is a solution for C and C++, which does not work in PHP. This is a PHP question, not a C or C++ question. Removing the tags.

Comment: @Leandros Thanks for your help. Out of curiosity, what's the solution for C and C++ ?

Comment: `goto`. It's a commonly used solution.

Comment: php 5.3+ does have [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can either use [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) (since PHP 5.3) or by adding another simple check.

```
$loopcheck = true;
for($i=1;some_test($i) && $loopcheck;$i++) {
       for($j=1;some_test($j) && $loopcheck;$j++) {
          for($k=1;some_test($k) && $loopcheck;$k++) {
             if(unicorn_test_for_three_parameters($i,$j,$k))  {
              $searchResult = array($i,$j,$k);
              $loopcheck = false;
              break;
             }
          }
          if(unicorn_test_for_two_parameters($i,$j)) {
            $searchResult = array($i,$j);
            $loopcheck = false;
            break;
           } 
       }
       if(unicorn_test_for_one_parameter($i)){
            $searchResult = array($i);
            $loopcheck = false;
        } 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.